# Argument evaluation

Tags: bash

Look at this bash script (script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "aaa"
echo "bbb"
...
echo $1
...
```

Now, i am trying to run this script this way:

```
./script.sh $(cat file1)
```

I have a problem:

the "cat file1" is run before script.sh. Bash is evaluating all arguments before running script.sh

I would like to run "cat file1" inside script.sh, on the "echo $1" line.

How can i do this ?

I have tried this:

```
./script.sh $(eval 'cat file1')
```

But it gives me the same result...

Thanks

Comment: what do you expect `echo cat file1` to generate? or is the intent to have the script run `cat file1`?

Comment: this is because script.sh is run with suid and i need root privilege to read file1

Comment: so you want the script to run `cat file1` for you?

Comment: if the intention is to pass a command to the script and have the script run the command for you ... this is a really, Really, REALLY bad idea, especially if the script is running under the suid of an admin account (eg, root) ... what happens when someone calls the script with `'rm -rf /'`?; if the sole purpose is to have the script `cat`  file then just pass the name of the file as an argument, have the script run some sanity checks (eg, `-f $1`) and then explicitly run `cat $1`

Comment: `./script.sh "$(cat file1)"`?

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is no way unless you can modify the script `script.sh`.

If you can modify `script.sh`, you can write your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$($1)"
```

Then call it in this way:

```
./script.sh "cat file1"
```

This means, you pass the command to be executed to the script and you echo the result of the executed command in the script.

But the above script is a little cumbersome. This one is simpler and would do the same:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
```

Comment: This approach will have problems dealing with filenames containing spaces. `./script.sh 'cat "file one.txt"'` -- that would require something like `eval "$1"`. But the larger point ("there is no way unless...") is spot-on.